# Mac os X does not boot if emulated with qemu/kvm on the WSL2

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, macos

I've enabled the KVM support on my WSL2 subsystem which run on top of my Windows 10 64 bit and I tried to boot mac os X. It's a shame that it didn't work because this error :

```
root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/mnt/i/macos-haxm# qemu-system-x86_64 -monitor stdio -no-reboot -machine q35 -m 16G -usb -device usb-kbd -device usb-tablet -device isa-applesmc,osk="ourhardworkbythesewordsguardedpleasedontsteal(c)AppleComputerInc" -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file=/mnt/i/macos-haxm/OVMF_CODE.fd -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=/mnt/i/MacOS-Haxm/OVMF_VARS-1024x768.fd -smbios type=2 -device ich9-intel-hda -device hda-duplex -device ide-drive,bus=ide.2,drive=Clover -drive id=Clover,if=none,snapshot=on,format=qcow2,file=/mnt/i/MacOS-Haxm/Clover.qcow2 -device ide-drive,bus=ide.1,drive=LinuxHDD -drive id=LinuxHDD,if=none,file=/mnt/i/MacOS-Haxm/images/hdd_catalina.img,format=qcow2 -device ide-drive,bus=ide.0,drive=LinuxDVD -drive id=LinuxDVD,if=none,snapshot=on,media=cdrom,file=/mnt/i/MacOS-Haxm/images/apple/highsierra.iso -netdev tap,id=net0,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no -device e1000-82545em,netdev=net0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:c9:18:27 -accel kvm
QEMU 4.2.0 monitor - type 'help' for more information
(qemu) qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit 2]
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5181:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
alsa: Could not initialize DAC
alsa: Failed to open `default':
alsa: Reason: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5181:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
alsa: Could not initialize DAC
alsa: Failed to open `default':
alsa: Reason: No such file or directory
audio: Failed to create voice `dac'
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5181:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
alsa: Could not initialize ADC
alsa: Failed to open `default':
alsa: Reason: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4693:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5181:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
alsa: Could not initialize ADC
alsa: Failed to open `default':
alsa: Reason: No such file or directory
audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
qemu-system-x86_64: -device ide-drive,bus=ide.2,drive=Clover: warning: 'ide-drive' is deprecated, please use 'ide-hd' or 'ide-cd' instead
qemu-system-x86_64: -device ide-drive,bus=ide.1,drive=LinuxHDD: warning: 'ide-drive' is deprecated, please use 'ide-hd' or 'ide-cd' instead
qemu-system-x86_64: -device ide-drive,bus=ide.0,drive=LinuxDVD: warning: 'ide-drive' is deprecated, please use 'ide-hd' or 'ide-cd' instead

**(qemu) qemu-system-x86_64 : warning : host does not support requested feature : CPUID.80000001H:ECX.svm [bit 2].**
```

Is there a way to fix that ? Check the image below,thanks.

[image: mac]

Comment: Have your checked this https://github.com/foxlet/macOS-Simple-KVM? I am not sure if this OSX will work with machine q35.

Comment: Also, have you tried to run other well known virtualized Linux over your  KVM/WSL2? just to be sure this is possible in WSL2

Answer (score 0):

macOS is designed to run only on Apple hardware, and as a consequence it only supports specific hardware.  It's likely that the emulated hardware isn't supported.

There are [projects](https://github.com/kholia/OSX-KVM) out there which can make it possible to run macOS in a VM, but be aware that the license for macOS permits it to run only on Apple hardware, so doing so may or may not be legal in your jurisdiction.

Comment: yeah,thanks,man,I have apple hardware.